# How to sort by count with groupby in dataframe spark

Tags: python, pyspark

I want to sort this count column by descending but I keep getting a 'NoneType' object is not callable error. How can I add a sort function to this so I won't get the error?

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import hour
hour = checkin.groupBy(hour("date").alias("hour")).count().show()
```

[image]

Comment: Remove `.show()` from the line, and then try again with your code.

Comment: How can I get it to sort by descending?

Comment: Posted an answer, you can try it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.show` is returning `None` which you can't chain any dataframe method after. Remove it and use `orderBy` to sort the result dataframe:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import hour, col
hour = checkin.groupBy(hour("date").alias("hour")).count().orderBy(col('count').desc())
```

Or:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import hour, desc
checkin.groupBy(hour("date").alias("hour")).count().orderBy(desc('count')).show()
```

Answer (score 0):

.show() returns None, so either assign the result to the variable hour than call hour.show() or don't assign like @Psidom suggest.

BTW, @Psidom doesn't work. The code below works with Spark 3.2 or above. I haven't checked the earlier version.

```
checkin.groupBy(hour("date").alias("hour")).count().orderBy('count', ascending=False).show()
```